# Getting exit code from SSH command running in background in Linux (Ksh script)

Tags: linux, ssh, ksh

I trying to run few commands to be executed in parallel in couple of remote servers using SSH and i need to get the correct exit code from those commands but with no success.
I am using the command below

```
(ssh -o LogLevel=Error "remote_server1" -n " . ~/.profile 1>&- 2>&-;echo "success" 2>&1 > /dev/null" ) & echo $? > /tmp/test1.txt
(ssh -o LogLevel=Error "remote_server2" -n " . ~/.profile 1>&- 2>&-;caname 2>&1 > /dev/null" ) & echo $? > /tmp/test2.txt
```

The result is always "0" (echo $?)  even i forced to failed like the second example above. Any idea?

Comment: What do you think `&` does?

Comment: to put the process in background. The question how to get the exit code from this process. Any idea?

Comment: you have to wait until the process finishes to get an "honest" return code, so that means you can't  use `&` to run it in the background. Or you have to craft a solution that writes the return value to a tmp file, then a separate process will have to check those files to see the status. Good luck.

Comment: `( ssh ...; echo $? > /tmp/test1.txt ) &`

Comment: @shellter, Thanks for that. That's what i am trying to to craft a solution to put the exit value in a tmp file...any idea?

Comment: In what way does it not work? If I run `(ssh user@host exit 40; echo $? >res)&`, afterwards `res` ends up containing `40` as expected.

Comment: @jhnc Sorry, I added BatchMode=yes to teh suggestion you made and it is working now. Much appreciated 

<code>(ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes -o LogLevel=Error "remove_server" "cuname"; echo $? > /tmp/test1.txt ) & 
remote_server> cat /tmp/test1.txt
127